# How would you latinized (medieval latin) the following surname "de Campenhout"

Tags: medieval-latin

I am currently writing a novel and would like to use a latinized version of the de germanic/Frankish surname "de Campenhout"
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What info do you have on the etymology of your surname?